# Percent escaping query url strings

Tags: ios, sdk, nsstring

I am getting NSString as given `http://maps.apple.com/maps?saddr=41.447910,-74.357881&daddr=719 Old Route 9 North, Wappingers Falls, NY 12590`

However i need to covert the above string into this one given for showing location in map

`http://maps.apple.com/maps?saddr=41.447910,-74.357881&daddr=719+Old%20Route+9+North%2CWappingers+Falls%2CNY+12590`

Please let me know.

Comment: Have you tried looking up `percentEscaping` for NSStrings.  Pretty sure it won't add the `+` sign for you, but it couldn't hurt looking into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An old question but this is what you need:

```
-(NSString*) encodeToPercentEscapeString:(NSString *)string {
return (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                        (CFStringRef) string,
                                        NULL,
                                        (CFStringRef) @"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                        kCFStringEncodingUTF8)); }

-(NSString*) decodeFromPercentEscapeString:(NSString *)string {
return (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NULL,
                                                        (CFStringRef) string,
                                                        CFSTR(""),
                                                        kCFStringEncodingUTF8)); }
```

Answer (score 9):

You can do this with the following...

```
NSString *theOrigString = @"http://maps.apple.com/maps?saddr=41.447910,-74.357881&daddr=719 Old Route 9 North, Wappingers Falls, NY 12590";

NSString *formattedString = [theOrigString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@", formattedString);
```

**Output**

```
http://maps.apple.com/maps?saddr=41.447910,-74.357881&daddr=719%20Old%20Route%2‌​09%20North,%20Wappingers%20Falls,%20NY%2012590
```

This will replace spaces with %20 and so on.

You can then use this as a url string.

Comment: Nope. You can't encode the whole URL that way. See my answer.

Comment: @DuncanC yep, you're wrong. Sorry. I just tried my two lines and NSLogged the result... `http://maps.apple.com/maps?saddr=41.447910,-74.357881&daddr=719%20Old%20Route%209%20North,%20Wappingers%20Falls,%20NY%2012590`

Comment: The stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: method sometimes works for certain purposes, but it usually isn't what you want, because it tries to encode an entire URL, which means that it does not encode any of the URL reserved characters.  So in this one weird situation, that method actually is correct, but only because the input is very unusual (a complete URL with percent encoding stripped, in which none of the originally percent-encoded characters were in the URL reserved character list).  The safer answer, of course, is "don't URL-decode the string on the way in...".

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `NSString`'s `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://maps.apple.com/maps?saddr=41.447910,-74.357881&daddr=719 Old Route 9 North, Wappingers Falls, NY 12590";

NSString *encodedString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

Comment: You cannot encode it this way. You have to encode the parameters separately.

Comment: Both DuncanC and @Sulthan are wrong here. This works exactly as Chris wrote it.

Comment: Hmmm seems to always work for me, I suppose it might be ideal to have the baseUrl separate and then append the encoded query string.

Comment: @ChrisWagner same, works for me too. Oh well. I like encoding the whole URL as it makes debugging the separates parts easier. I'm encoding a completely human readable URL rather than creating a URL from separate bits that are harder to read.

Comment: @Fogmeister, encoding the whole url only works if you can be sure that the string portions of the URL do not contain characters that serve as delimiters in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind the percent encoding simply comes down from the [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1). In a nutshell, you should percent escape values of your URI *query params* to escape the *reserved characters* ("!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]"). Doing so it is possible to properly decoding the encoded URI - supposing for the sake of simplicity same encoding on the both sides.

As pointed out by Duncan and Fogmeister, Apple's `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` is very *friendly* but, in general, wrong - or, at least, say, not compliant with RFC 3986 - since doesn't percent escape chars like "/:&%?".

A more general and robust solution would be something like

```
NSString * HKObjectToString(id object) {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", object];
}   

NSString * HKPercentEscapedString(id object, CFStringEncoding encoding) {
    NSString *string = HKObjectToString(object);
    return ((NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef) string, NULL,
                                                                              CFSTR("!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]"),
                                                                              encoding)));
}

...
@implementation NSDictionary (URLAdditions)
...
- (NSString *)percentEscapedQueryStringWithEncoding:(CFStringEncoding)encoding
{
    NSMutableArray *queryParts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSString *key in [self allKeys]) {
        NSString *part = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", HKPercentEscapedString(key, encoding), HKPercentEscapedString(HKObjectToString(self[key]), encoding)];
        [queryParts addObject:part];
    }
    return [queryParts componentsJoinedByString:@"&"];
}
...
@end 

...
@implementation NSString (StringHelper)
...
+ (NSString *)URIEncodedWithStringURI:(NSString *)baseURI queryParameters:(NSDictionary *)queryParams URIEncoding:(CFStringEncoding)encoding
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?%@", baseURI, [queryParams percentEscapedQueryStringWithEncoding:encoding]];
}
...
@end
```

For more details try to give a look at this public [repo](https://github.com/epacces/generalUtilities/tree/master/HKUtilities) on github.

Answer (score 0):

This question is problematic because the input data is damaged.  At some earlier point in the code, this URL got decoded as a single string.  You should never do that, because it can lead to situations where the distinction between different parts of the URL is lost and can never be recovered.  For example, suppose I have this URL:

http://www.example.com/folder/this%2Fthat.html

When decoded, this becomes

http://www.example.com/folder/this/that.html

and there's no way to turn that back into the original, because there's no way to know which of those slashes is real and which should be encoded as %2F.  The distinction is simply lost.

For this reason, when you work with URLs, it is important to always preserve them in their original form whenever possible, and when you have to decode a URL, to do so piecewise—that is, to start by splitting apart all of the path components, the query string, and so on, then pulling apart the fields in the query string (where applicable), and finally decoding each part individually.

After that, you would need to reencode each part by using CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding, because the NSString method above doesn't do percent encoding of slashes, ampersands, and other special URL characters.

But in your case, your best bet is to find the code that is decoding the URL, and rip it out so that you have the original, undamaged URL.  If and **only** if that is not possible, the stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: method can make a "best guess" about what to encode, so long as you understand that for arbitrary URLs, that solution won't necessarily work.

Answer (score -1):

Edited:

Sulthan has a point. You can't percent encode the whole URL if the string portion (like the address in this case) might contain reserved URL characters ("/", ":", "&", "%", "?", etc.)

The stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding method encodes spaces, but not slashes, colons, etc. Thus if the address string contains any of those, the receiver of the URL can't tell what's part of the syntax of the URL and what's data.

I have a category of NSString that escapes these characters as well:

The header

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSString (URLEncoding) 
- (NSString *)stringByAddingPercentEscapes;
- (NSString *)stringByReplacingPercentEscapes; 
@end 
NSString *mapURLStringTemplate = 
  @"http://maps.apple.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%@";
```

The body:

```
#import "StringCategory.h"

CFStringRef charsToEscape = CFSTR(":/&=");

@implementation NSString (URLEncoding) 

- (NSString *)stringByAddingPercentEscapes 
{ 
    return (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, 
                                                                (CFStringRef)self, NULL, charsToEscape, 
                                                                CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))); 
} 

- (NSString *)stringByReplacingPercentEscapes 
{ 
    return (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,(CFStringRef)self, CFSTR(""))); 
} 

@end
```

And to use it:

```
NSString *escapedAddressString = 
  [addressString stringByAddingPercentEscapes];

NSString *mapURLString = 
  [NSString stringWithFormat: mapURLStringTemplate, 
  latitude, 
  longitude, 
  escapedAddressString];
```

Comment: Nope, you can just encode the whole URL. You don't have to spend the time pulling it apart. Maybe it's because you're using ASCII encoding instead of UTF8?

Comment: Actually, it works with ASCII encoding too. Have you actually checked that it doesn't work. I think you'll be surprised.

Comment: @Fogmeister: Son of a gun, you're right. I have a custom category of NSString that escapes all the different characters from user-entered strings that would mess up URL parsing ("/", ":", "&", "%", "?", etc.) I use that. I guess I forgot that stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding did not escape those characters. The fact that it does not escape those characters is another source of problems, though. If there is a slash in the address string for example, it will potentially mess up the URL parsing. Granted a slash is not common in addresses, but it pays to fully format your data.